# Live Email Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I am looking to implement Live Email Content.

That is email Content that is updated at the time of the Email open - ideally.

If not possible, then at least at the time the email is first opened.

I can't find any reference to this anywhere, I think it should be possible referencing web based content.

What is possible in this space?

Thanks everyone for any input

Matt

Answer (score 1):

The only type of content you can render at open time is an image. Marketing Cloud deprecated it's Live Images feature a while ago, but you could consider vendors like [Movable Ink](https://movableink.com/). Their toolset can be integrated with Marketing Cloud using [their AppExchange application](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EuHRuUAN)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Einstein Content Selection](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_content_selection.htm&type=5) this serves images up on open time, can be expired, can be used for ABn testing, and you can also use rules to control which content is delivered